# Merge (or concat) two dataframes by index with duplicates index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe A and B with common indexes for A and B. These common indexes can appear several times (duplicate) for A and B.

I want to merge A and B in these 3 ways :

1. *Case 0:* If index `i` of `A` appear one time `(i1)` and index `i` for `B`
   appear one times `(i1)`, I want my merged by index dataframe to add
   the rows `A(i1), B(i1)`
2. *Case 1 :* If index `i` of `A` appear one time `(i1)` and index `i` for `B`
   appear two times in this order : `(i1 and i2)`, I want my merged by
   index dataframe to add the rows `A(i1), B(i1) and A(i1), B(i2)`.
3. *Case 2:* If index `i` of `A` appear two time in this order : `(i1, i2)` and
   index `i` for `B` appear two times in this order : `(i1 and i2)`, I want
   my merged by index dataframe to add the rows `A(i1), B(i1) and A(i2),
   B(i2)`.

These 3 cases are all of the possible case that could appear on my data.

When using pandas.merge, case 0 and case 1 works. But for case 2, the returned dataframe will add rows  `A(i1), B(i1) and A(i1), B(i2) and A(i2), B(i1) and A(i2), B(i2)` instead of `A(i1), B(i1) and A(i2), B(i2)`.

I could use pandas.merge method and then delete the undesired merged rows but is there a ways to combine these 3 cases at the same time ?

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 2], [5,5], [5,5], [1,1]], index=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'])
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [4, 8], [7,7], [5,5]], index=['b', 'c', 'a', 'a'])
pd.merge(A,B, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

For example, in the dataframe above, I want exactly it without the second and third index `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your 3 cases can be summarized into 2 cases:

1. Index i occur the same times (1 or 2 times) in A and B, merge according to the order.
2. Index i occur 2 times in A and 1 time in B, merge using B content for all rows.

Prep code:

```
def add_secondary_index(df):
    df.index.name = 'Old'
    df['Order'] = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
    df.set_index('Order', append=True, inplace=True)
    return df
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 2], [5,5], [5,5], [1,1]], index=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'])
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5], [4, 8], [7,7], [5,5]], index=['b', 'c', 'a', 'a'])
index_times = A.groupby(A.index).count() == B.groupby(B.index).count()
```

For case 1 is easy to solve, you just need to add the secondary index:

```
same_times_index = index_times[index_times[0].values].index
A_same = A.loc[same_times_index].copy()
B_same = B.loc[same_times_index].copy()
add_secondary_index(A_same)
add_secondary_index(B_same)
result_merge_same = pd.merge(A_same,B_same,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

For case 2, you need to seprately consider:

```
not_same_times_index = index_times[~index_times.index.isin(same_times_index)].index
A_notsame = A.loc[not_same_times_index].copy()
B_notsame = B.loc[not_same_times_index].copy()
result_merge_notsame = pd.merge(A_notsame,B_notsame,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

You could consider whether to add secondary index for `result_merge_notsame`, or drop it for `result_merge_same`.